# How to show several images in the same figue - Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

**EDITTED:**

Hii, 
sorry not mentioning it earlier, what I need to do is to display 6 images in the same figure at the same time. **Besides, at every image (frame) I need to draw some points (my code tracks the moves of the face - the eyes, nose, lips.)**
I have 246 images (frames)

this is the main functions I use:

```
   // The points/ coordinates of the lips, eyes and nose of the image "i".
Points = createPointsStructure (landmarks , i , NumOfLandarkPerFrame);
   // Draw landmarks and splines on the frame i (and draw/show the frame)
DrawAllPointsOnFace (pointArr , Points , img , 1  , position, i);
```

Any ideas how can I do it?

---

I need to write a code that displays 6 images in the same figure (at the same time). and lets the user to choose one of the images to edit it (by clicking on it).

Any help how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried "subplot" function?

Comment: Yes I have, but it didn't work as it should. Most of the figure was empty and the images were so small.

Comment: @HowaidaKhoureieh: can you show the code you have tried so far?

Comment: For example:subplot(2,2,1),imshow(rand(50,50))
, subplot(2,2,2),imshow(rand(50,50))
, subplot(2,2,3),imshow(rand(50,50))
, subplot(2,2,4),imshow(rand(50,50))

Comment: there is some gui programming here : http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f16-999044.html#f16-1003272

Comment: subplot(2,3,1); imshow(im1);
........
subplot(2,3,4); imshow(im4);
subplot(2,3,5); imshow(im5);
subplot(2,3,6); imshow(im6);

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a simple example to get you started:

```
function ImagesExample()
    %# read images in a cell array
    imgs = cell(6,1);
    for i=1:6
        imgs{i} = imread( sprintf('AT3_1m4_%02d.tif',i) );
    end

    %# show them in subplots
    figure(1)
    for i=1:6
        subplot(2,3,i);
        h = imshow(imgs{i}, 'InitialMag',100, 'Border','tight');
        title(num2str(i))
        set(h, 'ButtonDownFcn',{@callback,i})
    end

    %# mouse-click callback function
    function callback(o,e,idx)
        %# show selected image in a new figure
        figure(2), imshow(imgs{idx})
        title(num2str(idx))
    end
end
```

[image]

Another function to look into is the [MONTAGE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/montage.html) function from the IPT Toolbox:

```
%# given the above cell array `imgs`
montage( cat(4,imgs{:}) )
```

Comment: @Amro, Thanks alot for the answer. It is really useful. But I editted the question, and would be very happy if you helped me with it. Thanks again.