# Independent Component Analysis as Images

Tags: image, matlab, plot

I have applied Independent Component Analysis on set of face images using FastICA. I have successfully retrieved independent components and mixing matrix. The values of independent components are in double and I want to display these components as images like available on web, e.g., http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/imageica/. I don't know how to show this.

Answer (score 1):

One way you might do this more automatically is with the [`montage`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/montage.html) function. Or you can look at [`subimage`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/subimage.html). See also [this StackOverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769594/how-to-show-several-images-in-the-same-figue-matlab).

Answer (score 0):

Try the follwing function

```
function [XX,fh]=dispImgs(X,cols,gap,ihw,fh)
% Courtesy A. Leonardis, D. Skocaj
% see http://vicos.fri.uni-lj.si/danijels/downloads

[M,N]=size(X);
if nargin<2 cols=floor(sqrt(N)); end;
if nargin<3 gap=0; end;
if nargin<4 ihw=[sqrt(M),sqrt(M)]; end;
if nargin<5 fh = figure; end; % new figure

ih=ihw(1);iw=ihw(2);
maxv=max(X(:));
rows=floor(N/cols);
XX=zeros((rows*ih)+(rows-1)*gap,(cols*iw)+(cols-1)*gap)+maxv;

for i=1:N
   a=(iw+gap)*mod(i-1,cols)+1;
   b=(iw+gap)*mod(i-1,cols)+iw;
   c=(ih+gap)*(floor((i-1)/cols))+1;
   d=(ih+gap)*(floor((i-1)/cols))+ih;
   XX(c:d,a:b)=reshape(X(:,i)',ih,iw);
end;

xxmax=max(XX(:));
xxmin=min(XX(:));

fh = figure(fh);
imshow((XX-xxmin)/(xxmax-xxmin));
axis off;
```

Example:

```
X: imsize by N
dispImgs( X, 8, 4, imsize );%show all N images in 8 columns with Gap=4
```